# Check times a value is next to the same value in an array

Tags: c#

Lets say I have this array on C#:

```
int myList = {1,4,6,8,3,3,3,3,8,9,0}
```

I want to know if a value (lets say from 0-9) is next to itself in the list and how many times. In this case, the value 3 is next to itself and it has 4 repetitions. If I have a list {0,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7} the value 5 is next to itself and has 2 repetitions.

Repetitions have a limit of 5. No value can be repeated more than 5 times. The far I went is making if statements, but I know there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2014/10/missing-stackoverflow-topic-terrible-question/

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: So what if you have `{3,3,3, 5,5, 7,7,7}`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show? What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!   _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_.  Also, I removed `unity3d` tag since question is nothing about unity3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard of question is not that good but writing the answer

```
int lastValue = myList[0];
        int times = 0;
        foreach (int value in myList) {
            if (lastValue == value) {
                times++;
            }
            else if (times <= 1) {
                lastValue = value;
                times = 1;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
```

You only have to iterate on your list and keep a counter that will count only the consecutive duplicate integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a neater solution, you might look at using an open source library called [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) (by Jon Skeet and few others) on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq). It has useful extension methods for LINQ.

One of them is called `GroupAdjacent`, which is applicable to your problem.

```
var testList = new[] { 1, 4, 6, 8, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 9, 0 };
var groups = testList.GroupAdjacent(t => t);

var groupsWithMoreThanOneMember = groups.Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```